# Objective-c App crashing in iOS 13(Search bar issue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

Please someone help me I am not familiar with Objective-c. App is crashing in iOS 13
found the following error in console

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Missing or detached view for search bar layout. The application must not remove > from the hierarchy.'**

Search bar code

```
 UIImageView *searchBackView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 320, 30)];
    searchBackView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search1.gif"];
    searchBackView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    searchBackView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [tableHeader addSubview:searchBackView];

  searchBar=[[[UISearchBar alloc] init] autorelease];
    searchBar.delegate=self;
    [searchBar setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    searchBar.barStyle = UISearchBarIconClear;
    searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(17, 3, 285, 30);
    [searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search1.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    searchBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [searchBackView addSubview:searchBar];
    [searchBackView release];
    [tableHeader addSubview:label];

        for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews)
        {
            for (UIView *secondLevelSubview in subView.subviews){
        if ([secondLevelSubview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            [secondLevelSubview removeFromSuperview];
        }
            }
        }



    searchField = nil;
        for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews)
        {
            for (UIView *secondLevelSubview in subView.subviews){
                if ([secondLevelSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                {
                    searchField = (UITextField *)secondLevelSubview;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
        {
            for (UIView *secondLevelSubview in subview.subviews){
                if ([secondLevelSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
                {
                    [(UITextField *)secondLevelSubview setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
                }
            }
        }
 if (searchField) {
    searchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    }
    BluemenAppDelegate *delegate=(BluemenAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (isShowlist==YES) {
        delegate.search_string = @"";
        searchBar.text = delegate.search_string;
        isShowlist = NO;
    }

        searchBar.text = delegate.search_string;
```

**Update**

Now I am able launch app but now if click on any textfield in app it is crashing and giving **XPC connection interrupted** error

Comment: can you change the `searchBar=[[[UISearchBar alloc] init] autorelease];` to `searchBar=[[UISearchBar alloc] init];`and delete the `[searchBackView release];`line and try?

Comment: Tried but No luck :-( and if I comment  `[secondLevelSubview removeFromSuperview];` line then App is not crashing but search bar giving issue if I do that

Comment: Just so I can understand what you are trying to achieve, do you want a clear searchBar? Can you please post a screenshot of how it was looking and how it looks if you don't remove the mentioned view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to achieve a SearchBar with a clear background. As seen on the error message, iOS 13 won't allow `UISearchBarBackground` to be removed. There is a work around you can try:

This will make the search background image to be transparent, without removing it.

```
for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *secondLevelSubview in subView.subviews){
        if ([secondLevelSubview isKindOfClass: [UIImageView class]]) {
            secondLevelSubview.alpha = 0.0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Just replace this part of your code with this one and check if it attends what you are expecting.

Comment: @summerfin3 Thanks for the response. When I tried by replacing with the code you shared, I am able to launch the app without any crash but when I click on the search bar it is crashing and giving **XPC connection interrupted** error in console

Comment: Hmm, the code might be getting caught in one of those loops. Try adding break; after the instructions on each of those for statements.

Comment: Same issue even after adding breaks in loop . I am guessing that there might be some issue with search bar textfield in iOS 13.

Comment: Probably, a lot has changed about SearchBar on iOS 13. I made a snippet on how I would implement this, maybe it can be useful for you https://pastebin.com/ByP738bq

Comment: @summerfin3 thanks for your effort. I've implemented your code but there is no change, getting same error when I click on the text field. But I noticed something here this problem is not only for search bar text field, previously I used to click on search bar text field only because app is already logged in, now I logged out and clicked on one of the text field  to login and now here also I am getting the same **XPC connection interrupted** error.